# What's the preferred way to load web application specific configuration and settings in java

Tags: java, configuration, settings, war

I was wondering what is the usual way for you to load application settings in web applications. I'm just looking around because I had only needed this once and we required user to specify environment variable with path set to the configuration file which we loaded in the spring context. My point is not the loading (whether xml or properties) but the location and locating of the file, what do you think is the preferred way.

Regards,

Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing `properties` file in **User's home directory** is a good option

Comment: Yep, this seems reasonable for both nix and ms customers.

Comment: For a *webapplication*? Just how would the webapplication access the file system on the clients?

Comment: Just FYI, on some Linux distributions the init srcipts can dispatch application server under different user than root. E.g. Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu runs under user tomcat6 and it's home resides in /usr/share/tomcat6. So be sure to check the process owner and /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but storing settings either in a properties text file locally, or in a database table are two common ways.

Answer (score 1):

We usually populate the JNDI environment in the context descriptor.