# Why I cant read properties file using getResourceAsStream when it is in classpath (under WEB-INF/lib)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, properties

I was testing out reading a properties file using getResourceAsStream when the properties file is in classpath (under WEB-INF\lib folder). And it is not working for some reason. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my environment: Operating system is Windows 7. IDE is Eclipse 4.2.3 Kepler 64-bit. Server is Tomcat 6.0.37 running on 8081 port.

I created a web application **MyWebProject**.

I have a `app.properties` file which is located in `WEB-INF\lib` folder. This is  the content of `app.properties` file:

> DataSource=jdbc/MyDB

I created a class `AppProperties` which reads this file. This is the class:

```
public final class AppProperties {

    private static String DATA_SOURCE_NAME;

    public static String getDataSourceName() {
        return DATA_SOURCE_NAME;
    }

    static {

        ClassLoader classLoader = null;
        InputStream propertiesFile = null;
        Properties properties = null;
        final String PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME = "app.properties";

        properties = new Properties();
        classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        System.out.println("AppProperties: Name of classLoader = " + classLoader.getClass().getName());
        propertiesFile = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME);
        System.out.println("AppProperties: propertiesFile = " + propertiesFile);

    }
}
```

Then I created a Servlet `AppPropertiesServlet` to test it out:

```
public class AppPropertiesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public AppPropertiesServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
        String dataSourceName = null;

        dataSourceName = AppProperties.getDataSourceName();
    }
}
```

I deployed the web application **MyWebProject** on Tomcat. So under `webapps` folder of Tomcat, a new folder `MyWebProject` was created with all the necessary files. I then run the servlet `http://localhost:8081/MyWebProject/AppPropertiesServlet` 
and this is what appears on Tomcat console:

> AppProperties: Name of classLoader =
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 
>  AppProperties:
>   propertiesFile = null

Why the propertiesFile is null? The `app.properties` file is in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of `MyWebProject` folder but somehow the classloader is unable to find it. Strange. What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: usually classpath contains all the jars under `WEB-INF/lib`, try making it so it puts it under `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thanks. Usually where are the properties files put?

Comment: depends, if properties file is something that needs to be changed without redeploying application, [externalize it ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379607/whats-the-preferred-way-to-load-web-application-specific-configuration-and-sett)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be under `WEB-INF/lib` it has to be packaged inside the JAR.

If you want it to be like a normal file , it has to be inside `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Thanks. Usually where are the properties files put?